# Can I batch set the date on Canon RAW files with a tool?

Tags: canon, raw, metadata, date

I have just noticed my cameras date has been wrong for the last month.
However it is consistently wrong, so if I work out (or guess) the date and time of the first photograph, is there a tool that will work out the correct date/time of the rest of the images?

Comment: Windows, Mac, Linux? Do you own Photoshop or Lightroom? Have you seen http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/how-to-shift-exif-date-time-created-by-time-in-days-hours-minutes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes — either ExifTool or Exiv2 will do this and can work on RAW files, including CR2. And they work on Linux, Mac, or Windows.

Comment: Do you know of a link with instructions on how to offset all Canon .CR2 files by a set amount (one hour) using ExifTool?