# Batch edit exif datetime of a period of time

Tags: software, metadata

I'm looking for a tool that enables me to edit the EXIF date and time of multiple images over a specific period of time.

For example, the first image should have time 09:00
And the last image should have time 12:00
The images in between should randomly have a time between 09:00 and 12:00

Is there a tool for this?

Comment: @Janas Then why is there a [tag:software] tag with the description "_Questions related to the tools used for digital image editing, processing, **organization**, distribution, and presentation should have this tag_"  ??

Comment: **organization** is probably to be understood as **photography cataloging** or **photography managing**. We often have questions about EXIF and the useful software **ExifTool** but about half of those are really about programming, such as yours. Is it indeed borderline to photography, as it is more about metadata editing than taking and managing images.

Answer (score 3):

[ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) might be the tool for you.

What you want is [writing tags](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#writing), probably the tags *CreateDate*, *ModifyDate* and *DateTimeOriginal*. As modifying date and time is a common problem, the author created a specific *group tag* called *AllDates*.

You can use this command :

```
exiftool -AllDates='2017:02:05 10:11:05' -overwrite_original IMG_01.jpg
```

Now, if you want to automize it, you need to know some programming language. You can get inspired by looking at those related questions:

- [Is there a free program to (batch) change photo file's date to match EXIF?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/27245/is-there-a-free-program-to-batch-change-photo-files-date-to-match-exif)
- [How to shift EXIF date/time created by time in days, hours, minutes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/7919/how-to-shift-exif-date-time-created-by-time-in-days-hours-minutes)